# How to notify a user everytime an update is done

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to notify a user that someone has sent a message to her(for example) without refreshing the page.  I am using php and jquery(AJAX) to handle this. I am planning to code it using setTimeout(); on javascript to  retrieve the data on the database without refreshing the current page. However, the problem is I think, it will weaken the search and will cause of delay if I have more users in the future.

Do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Take a look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

Implement [WebSockets](http://www.websocket.org/). There is this [jQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/) allowing you to use Websockets while gracefully degrading for non-supporting browsers. On the PHP side, there is this [class](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) which seems to be the most widely used for PHP WS servers

Answer (score 0):

Websocket solves this problem, but adds several new problems (separate port, ws-server restart). 
Twitter makes GET requests every 60 seconds:

```
GET https://twitter.com/i/notifications?oldest_unread_id=0
```